# Unclear Compile-time Java Error

Tags: java, casting, compilation

I'm running into peculiar behavior in terms of compile time errors with the following code (I'm using JDK7):

```
public class classA { public void foo( List<Object> o ){} }

public class classB<T>{ public void bar( List<Object> o ){} }
```

We consider the the following test object

```
List<String> o = new ArrayList<String>();
```

There is no way to get java to compile by passing *o* as a parameter to the method *foo* of class *classA*, and as far as I can figure, there shouldn't be.

Now say we're in the main method of classB and try to just call *bar* without instantiating an instance of classB to call it on. I might expect to get a *non-static method can't be called from static context* compilation error like I would if I tried to pull that in classA, but instead I get a conversion invocation error. That, makes sense - the types don't line up.

**However** if I try call bar from a nonstatic context, as in

```
ClassB b = new classB(); 
b.bar( o );
```

Java seems to forgive me for not lining up the types and runs the code no problem. I haven't done anything to fix the issue of typcasting, so why does Java let this code execute, where it wouldn't with classA?

**Edit:** In response to some questions. classA is given just for reference - it isn't supposed to compile and I don't expect it to, so I can't offer code that compiles with it. The code for classB that DOES compile and execute might be given by:

```
public class classB<T> {
    public void bar( List<Object> o ){}

    public static void main( String[] args ){ 
        classB b = new classB();
        List<String> o = new ArrayList<String>();
        b.bar( o );
    }

}
```

This code compiles and executes. The exact same code *without* the  generic declaration in the class declaration line does not work. I understand type erasure, which someone eluded to, but how does it help, since T is not references in the method bar or the main code

Also, there are tons of ways to make this code better. I'm really just looking for an explanation of its behavior

Comment: Please don't use the word "exception" to mean "compile error".  An exception is something completely different.

Comment: Please provide actual code that compiles. With your snippets there is no way to tell what you are really looking at.

Comment: Are you missing the word `class` from the second line of your snippet?  Or are you doing something REALLY weird?

Comment: Did you mean to use `T` anywhere in classB?

Comment: @Thilo - how do you expect the OP to do that (provide actual code that compiles) when their actual problem is that the code doesn't compile?

Comment: @DavidWallace: OP says it does compile, contrary to expectations. However with all the spelling mistakes, missing keywords and typos in the samples, it's hard to tell what is going on.

Comment: the op wants to know why the presence of <T> makes the code compile

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Did you do a clean build? If the prior compiled, erasure would allow the latter to compile using a `List<String>`.

Comment: It's a sad day when we all spend more time guessing what the question was supposed to be, rather than answering it.  You'd think that people who want help would actually take more care in getting it right.

Comment: Sorry for poor quality guys, what can I do to clarify more?

Comment: I do NOT mean to use T anywhere in the method - that why it's confusing me that it compiles

Comment: Right.  I understand now what you're asking, and I have retracted my close vote.  That's a very good question and I wish I knew the answer.

Comment: note that it will also compile if Class B is defined as:

    `class  classB<T>{ public void bar( List<Float> o ){} }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limitation in how generics are implemented.

They are opt-in.

```
classB b = new classB();
```

Here, you are opting out of generics, and you do get a warning.

```
Note: classB.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
```

**When you opt-out of generic type checking, you don't get any of it, for the whole class, even for methods that do not use the bound type `T`.**

As @vandale points out, with generics turned off, you could even get the code compiled with

```
 public void bar( List<Float> o );
```

If you do a

```
classB<Object> b = new classB<Object>();
```

it will not compile anymore.

Comment: I think I'm not understanding this right, but if I opt OUT of generics by using your first line of code, then shouldn't it operate the same way that a class declared without generics would operate - like classA, which didn't compile?

Comment: classA is *not* declared without generics. It still uses `List<Object>` in the method definition. It is just itself not a generic class. If you disable generics for classB, not even that part will work. It's all or nothing.

Answer (score 4):

When you define the class as

```
class ClassB<T>
```

but instantiate it as

```
new ClassB().bar(new ArrayList<String>());
```

you're actually using a raw type (without generics) version of it. If you notice the warning about the type safety; the method signature is `bar(List)` instead of `bar(List<Object>)`:

> Type safety: The method **bar(List)** belongs to the raw type ClassB. References to generic type ClassB should be parameterized.

If you pass the parameterized type `T` as, say, `String`

```
new ClassB<String>().bar(new ArrayList<String>());
```

it doesn't compile with the error (notice the method signature again)

```
The method **bar(List<Object>)** in the type ClassB<String> is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<String>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
public void method(List<? extends Object> o) { /* body */ }
```

This way it will accept any list whose generic type argument is a descendent of Object, the way you want. :)

Comment: yes that works, but I'm trying to explain the behavior I'm seeing, not find better alternative. Your's is definitely better than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Java still produces an "unchecked" warning, but it is able to compile because of [erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html); that is, the type List<T> and List<E> use the same, non-generic underlying type in the Java virtual machine. You can think of generics as merely syntactic sugar for inserting casts at the call sites and for doing some additional checking, but in the bytecode that the compiler emits, it's as if T and E were replaced with Object everywhere, and so the compiler is able to treat this as a warning and not an error.

Comment: That would be it, if `T` was actually used in the method definition of classB, which at least according to the snippet (which does not even have a class keyword) it is not.

Comment: Exactly, T is not supposed to be anywhere in the method. I added the context, hope that helps